# Unable to open QGIS browser on Mac OSX

Tags: qgis, qgis-browser

I recently installed QGIS 3.2.2-Bonn on my 2014 Macbook pro running OSX 10.13.6 (17G65), however, I am unable to open the standalone browser tool that looks like this:

[image: QGIS Browser]

I am unable to open the browser tool because I cannot locate the standalone application. According to this website: [QGIS Browser Tutorial](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/using_qgis_browser.html)

I should be able to locate the application in the following directory:

```
QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/QGIS Browser.app
```

but when I go to that path, there is no QGIS Browser.app file. All I see is this:
[image: Missing File]

I downloaded and installed QGIS via the standard installer from the QGIS website:
[Download QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)

I'm just trying to open QGIS browser and instead where I expect the application to be located, it is not. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

QGIS3 doesn't seem to have a standalone browser application - instead, use the browser *panel*:

`View | Panels | Browser`

[image]